# Updating State of StatefulWidget from other StatefulWidget in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, animation, boolean

i am trying to update the state of the animated switcher in the middle area. i am trying to do this using a setstate in the lower area. but it does not work.

1. the first thing i did is to create a variable with a boolean data type in the home class.
2. then i passed the variable to both the middle area and the lower area
3. the idea was that if the same variable is passed to the class whose state i am trying to update, and the class with the set state, it would work. but it seems i am wrong. i would appreciate some assistance.
   the boolean variable i am trying to make work is the _rep variable

This is the Home widget

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Offset> _animation;
  late Animation<Offset> _anime;
    bool _rep = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2)
    );
    _animation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin:Offset (0.0, 0.0),
      end: Offset (0.0,3.0),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.easeIn));

    _anime = Tween<Offset>(
      begin:Offset (0.0, 0.0),
      end: Offset (0.0,-0.55),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: Curves.easeIn));

    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Padding(
          padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.h),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                   TopIcon(icons: Icons.arrow_back, color:Colors.grey.shade300 ,),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 13.h,
                      width: 13.w,
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/download.png')
                  ),
                  TopIcon(icons: Icons.shopping_bag_outlined, color: Colors.grey.shade300,),
                ],
              ),
               SizedBox(
                height: 3.h,
              ),
               Text('Frappuccino',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 27.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
              ),
               Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                 child: Text('White Chocolate',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade400
                  ),
              ),
               ),
              MiddleArea(
                     controller: _animationController,
                     animation: _animation,
                     rep: _rep,


              ),



               LowerArea(controller: _animationController, anime: _anime, rep = _rep),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the middle area

```
class MiddleArea extends StatefulWidget {
   MiddleArea({Key? key, required this.controller, required this.animation, required this.rep}) : super(key: key);
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Offset> animation;
  final bool rep;


  @override
  State<MiddleArea> createState() => _MiddleAreaState();
}

class _MiddleAreaState extends State<MiddleArea> {
  bool _flag = true;
  bool _favourite = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.rep);
    return SizedBox(
      height: 52.h,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 135.0),
                  child: Text('STARBUCKS',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Typette',
                        color: Colors.brown.shade200,
                        fontSize: 30.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text('STARBUCKS',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Typette',
                      color: Colors.brown.shade100,
                      fontSize: 30.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                  ),
                ),
                Text('STARBUCKS',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Typette',
                      color: Colors.brown.shade50,
                      fontSize: 30.sp,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

          Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: const [
                  SizeAndFave(text: 'Preference'),
                  SizeAndFave(text: 'Fave!')
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {
                         _flag = !_flag;
                      });
                    },
                      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation){
                          return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child,);
                        },
                        child: widget.rep == true?Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                          key: const Key('1'),
                          child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.brown.shade300,
                                      width: 3
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                              ),
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.coffee_outlined,
                                  size: 20,
                                ),
                              )
                          ),
                        ):null,
                      )
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {
                        _favourite = !_favourite;
                      });
                    },
                      child: _favourite? TopIcon(icons: Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.brown.shade300)
                      :TopIcon(
                          icons: Icons.favorite, color: Colors.brown.shade300)
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
              AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
                  return FadeTransition( opacity: animation,
                  child: child);
                },
                  child: _flag == true ? Center(
                    key: const Key('1'),
                    child: SlideTransition(
                      position: widget.animation,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 80.h,
                        width: 80.w,
                         child: Image.asset('assets/images/starcup.png'),
                       ),
                    ),
                  ):Center(
                    key: const Key('2'),
                    child: SlideTransition(
                      position: widget.animation,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 80.h,
                        width: 80.w,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/greeen.png'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                   ),
          Positioned(
              child:
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.h),
              child: TopIcon(
                  icons: Icons.car_crash_outlined, color: Colors.brown.shade300),
            ),
          )),

          const Positioned(
              child:
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 330.0, left: 14),
                  child: Text('\$ 5.99',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 27,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),
                  ),
                ),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

and lastly, the lower area

```
class LowerArea extends StatefulWidget {
  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation<Offset> anime;
  bool rep;




   LowerArea({Key? key, required this.controller, required this.anime, required this.rep}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LowerArea> createState() => _LowerAreaState();
}

class _LowerAreaState extends State<LowerArea> {
  bool _bigger = true;
  bool _fade = true;

  void move(){

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children:  [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.h),
                child: const Text('Tall Frappuccino',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.h),
                child: const Text('Swipe Down',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.h),
                child: const Text('Pickup',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SlideTransition(
          position: widget.anime,

          child: AnimatedContainer(
            // height: 11.h,
            width: _bigger ? 35.h: 80.h,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.loose,
              children: [
                Center(child: Image.asset('assets/images/baggie.png')),
                Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:  EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.h),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                           widget.controller.forward();
                           setState(() {
                             _bigger = !_bigger;
                             _fade = !_fade;
                             widget.rep = !widget.rep;

                             print('this is fade $_fade ');

                           });
                      },
                      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation){
                          return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child,);
                        },
                        child: _fade? Container(
                          key: Key('1'),
                          height: 8.h,
                          width: 7.w,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children:  [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.3.h),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.lock_outline,
                                  color: Colors.white54,
                                  size: 2.5.h,

                                ),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                color: Colors.white12,
                                size: 3.h,
                              ),



                            ],
                          ),
                        ):null,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `provider` pacakges  https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Create a class that inherits the functions of ChangeNotifyer to create a flag to control and create a setter.
**provider class**

```
class StateController extends ChangeNotifier{
   bool _req = false;
   bool get req => _req; //getter
  
   setReqValue(){
      _req = !_req;
      notifyListener(); 
   }
}
```

Declare the provider class in the `main` function. You can change the location of the declaration according to `Wiget tree`, but first declare it in main
**Change main.dart**

```
void main(){
  runApp(
    Multiprovider(
      providers: [
         ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => StateController()),
      ],
      child: HomePage(),
    )
  );
}
```

The UI is updated by `notifyListener()`.
**change UI**

```
child: context.watch<StateController>().req == true ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                          key: const Key('1'),
                          child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.brown.shade300,
                                      width: 3
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                              ),
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.coffee_outlined,
                                  size: 20,
                                ),
                              )
                          ),
                        ):null,
```

**Change State**

```
onTap: (){
                           widget.controller.forward();
                           setState(() {
                             _bigger = !_bigger;
                             _fade = !_fade;
                             context.read<StateController>().setReqValue();

                             print('this is fade $_fade ');

                           });
                      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am too lazy to try understand your code. But if you want to update state of the page after you pop from Navigation to it.

In page you want to update

```
Navigation.push(context, /* Page that will change something */)
  // Future will trigger then you return to this page.
  .then((_) => setState(() {}))
```